# Excel Interop - get table style colors

Tags: excel, office-interop, com-interop, office-automation, excel-tables

I work with Excel Interop, I try to get color of rows from specyfic Table Style.

I get name of Table Style like that:

```
var TableStyle = table.TableStyle.Name.ToString();
```

But I haven't got idea how get colors from known style.

Answer (score 0):

I soloved my problem.

If somebody will have similar in the future.

You can access to table in that way:

```
var tse = table.TableStyle.TableStyleElements;
double rs1 = ((TableStyleElement)tse[5]).Interior.Color;
double rs2 = ((TableStyleElement)tse[6]).Interior.Color;
```

when indexes of tse is an enum:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xltablestyleelementtype?view=excel-pia

But If you need create new style, you should copy existing and edit.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/hh273483(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN